# Qt custom geoservice plugin

Tags: c++, qt, qml

Использую Map компонент под QML и кровь из носа нужно сделать поддержку различных поставщиков карт, таких как Yandex, Google, Yahoo и т.д. Стараюсь реализовывать все стандартными средствами. Пока получается, кроме того о чем сабж. Из коробки в Qt поддержка только HERE, OSM и mapbox.

В существующем, урезанном, кустарном Qt Widget варианте все свелось к тому, чтобы просто изменить ссылку с osm на яндекс. Неужели я не могу как-нибудь наследовать один из классов плагина и переопределить функцию, делающую запрос к серверу?

Я нашел такое решение https://habrahabr.ru/post/233809/ . Но здесь нужно делать форк QtLocation, а это уже на мой взгляд костыльно, т.к. Qt необходимо будет пересобирать и он просто так на другой машине не скомпилируется. http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/44476-creating-custom-mapping-plugin-for-QtLocation вот еще, но я не могу разобраться, т.к. парень приводит не весь код.

### UPD

Код в последней, приведенной мной статье старенький

Answer (score 1):

Слышал я как-то про marble на KDE. Так вот, эта штука кое-как работает. https://marble.kde.org Опыт показал, что в случае, если нужны сторонние провайдеры, проще использовать его, правда придется допилить.

**РЕШЕНИЕ**
А ларчик открывался довольно просто. Во-первых, ссылка https://github.com/vladest/googlemaps Это чей-то готовый плагин. Загружаете его себе на компьютер удобным способом. Далее в консоли MinGW (в меню пуск есть такой) осуществляете переход в папку с файлом googlemaps.pro (команда cd) выполняете три команды:

```
qmake googlemaps.pro
mingw32-make
mingw32-make install
```

Как внутри работают плагины расписано тут https://habrahabr.ru/post/233809/

Сейчас я парюсь над тем как поместить яндекс на тайловую сетку гугла или переделать эту сетку вообще, т.к. яндекс и гугл имеют разные проекции